# How to get alt text of a table in a excel worksheet

Tags: c#, excel

How to get alt text of a table in a excel worksheet?

I have this code to open a Excel Workbook, but how do I get the Alternative Text of a table in a woorksheet?

```
string filePath = @"C:\Temp\ExcelTable.xlsx";

Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();

Excel.Workbook excel_wbk = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath);

// This work if there is a shape in Worksheet 1:

string altTextShape = excel_wbk.Worksheets[1].Shapes[1].AlternativeText

// Code to get excel table alt text?

// excel_wbk.Worksheets[1].Tables[1].AlternativeText  
// or excel_wbk.Worksheets[1].Table[1].AlternativeText doesn't exist

excelApp.Quit();
```

Comment: I figured it out by myself:

Comment: Excel.Worksheet ws = excel_wbk.Worksheets[1];

Comment: string altText = ws.ListObjects[1].AlternativeText

Answer (score 0):

Alternative text doesn't exist on tables, check out this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.ipivottable.alternativetext?view=excel-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Excel_IPivotTable_AlternativeText) and you'll see that alternative text is available for pivot tables and shapes and not much else.